Quadratic with integer coefficients and $m$, $n$ such that $f(m)=n$ and $f(n)=m$
Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Given that there exist two distinct integers $m$ and $n$ such that $f(m)=n$ and $f(n)=m$, prove that the equation $f(x)=x$ has at least one irrational solution.
My ideas so far are as follows: First of all, the equation clearly has two real solutions since the function $g(x):= f(x)-x$ is a quadratic and satisfies
$$g(m)\cdot g(n) = -(m-n)^2 <0.$$
If we try to use the fact that $f$ has integer coefficients, we obtain from the conditions $f(m)=n$ and $f(n)=m$ that
$$b^2-4a(c-n) = k^2$$
$$b^2-4a(c-m) = l^2$$
for some integers $k,l$. Also, the conclusion is equivalent to $(b-1)^2 - 4ac$ is not a perfect square. I could not continue any further.

This might help:  Since $an^2+bn+c=m$ and $am^2+bm+c=n$ we can subtract to get get $a(n^2-m^2)+b(n-m)=m-n\implies -a(n+m)=b$.

@lulu Yep, this might help, but pls check your implication.

The polynomial $p(x)=f(x)-(m+n-x)$ is such that $p(n)=p(m)=0$, so it has the form $p(x)=k(x-m)(x-n)$ for an integer $k\neq 0$. Now $f(x)=x$ is equivalent to
$kx^2-x(2+km+kn)+(kmn+m+n)=0$, which has discriminant
$$\Delta=k^2(m-n)^2+4.$$
Since there are no positive integer solutions to $a^2+4=b^2$ (if it's not clear to you I'll add the proof) we are done.

The solution $(b,c)$ of the Cramer system
$$bn+c=m-an^2,\quad bm+c=n-am^2$$
is
$$b=-1-a(m+n),\quad c=m+n+amn.$$ Substituting, we get
$$(b-1)^2-4ac=4+a^2(m-n)^2,$$
which cannot be a perfect square. Indeed, if $\alpha:=|a(m-n)|\ge2$ then $\alpha^2+4<(\alpha+1)^2$.
